# error while i Lanch AVD Manger in android studio

Tags: android

emulator: device fd:884
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 1024 MB
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, as it says you need to reduce your AVD Ram size, You could edit it in your AVD Manager. 
Or you may use some third party emulators too, My favourite Android Emulator for app testing is 'Genymotion' you may choose a free licenses for personal use.